# Need to restore default 11.10 graphics. How do I do it?

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I switched off the "Animations" options in the CCSM manager by mistake. This removed all the window decorations, removed Unity, and even the top menu bar which has the shutdown menu I restarted, but it didn't make any difference. The login screen is fine. All I see after login is the wallpaper. How do I "undo" this mistake? I can use keyboard shortcuts, and hence, access the terminal. Also, when I tried to restart unity from terminal, this is what I see, after which it doesn't show anything else:

```
shashwat@shashwat302:~$ unity
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing snap options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing session options...done
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x3200044
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x28002d4
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x28002e2
```

What should I do?

Comment: I solved the problem myself. I started CCSM manager through the terminal and started the Unity Plugin, resolved the conflicts, and rebooted :) It was done! :)

Comment: Please post that as answer, it's not forbidden to answer your own questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
unity --reset
```

Should reset all your compiz (including unity) settings to the default values.